# Adjust sorting for specific custom biblatex bibliography driver

Tags: biblatex

I am currently writing a custom bibliography driver in a authoryear style, because I had to introduce a new bibtex type called "din-norm", which then in turn I will use to cite a DIN Norm (which is kind of some standard.

I want it to look like this ultimately

DIN ISO 2330:2013-07 (2013) Begriffe und Benennungen - Allgemeine Grundsätze. Beuth-Verlag, Berlin

which i achieved using this:

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{din-norm}{%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcolon}%
  \printfield{year}%
  -%
  \thefield{month}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printtext[parens]{%
    \printfield{year}}%
  \setunit{\addspace}\newblock
  \printfield{title}%
  \newunit\newblock
  \usebibmacro{publisher+location+date}
  \usebibmacro{finentry}}
```

Only problem is: currently the authoryear style uses `sorting=nty`, which is fine. But in this case (the DIN does not have an author) the entry will be sorted according to title - but I want (and only for this specific type `din-norm`) it to be sorted after its number (which in this case is `DIN ISO 2330`).

How can I change the sorting scheme to reflect this but only for this specific driver/bibtex type?

**Edit:**

I currently use a workaround, since I am manually filling in `sortkey` and `label` (I also want the citation to look a specific well, which I currently don't know how to do best). Here is my bibtex entry:

My bibtex entry currently looks like this:

```
@din-norm{DIN-2330:2013aa,
    Address = {Berlin},
    Institution = {DIN Deutsches Institut f{\"u}r Normung e.\,V.},
    Sortkey = {DIN 2330:2013-07},
    Label = {DIN 2330},
    Month = {07},
    Number = {DIN 2330},
    Publisher = {Beuth-Verlag},
    Title = {Begriffe und Benennungen -- Allgemeine Grunds{\"a}tze},
    Year = {2013}}
```

I know there is a way to map specific entry fields to other entry fields. How would I achieve mapping `number` to `label` and `number`+`:`+`year`+`month` to `sortkey` automatically?

All the best,
David

Comment: Check out [how to adapt the sorting of a custom type `@standard` in using biblatex/biber](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300010/35864). If that can't help you, I for one would really appreciate a full example to play round with so I can test my ideas.

Comment: Hey @moewe, I edited my question with some more information. I looked at your answer with the source mapping technique and I think with a little help it might be useful to get my desired result after all :)

Comment: Do you need any more help? Since an MWE is still missing I wouldn't be able to test my ideas properly, but if you want I can jot something down for you.

Comment: Sorry, I have had little time the past few days. I'll try to give you an proper answer and MWE over the weekend :)

Comment: Any news here? I feel this question is pretty much a duplicate of the question linked to above.

Comment: I have decided to close your question as a duplicate since at it stands right now it really is a duplicate to me. If you disagree, please edit your question with a full MWE and explain how the other answer does not work for you. Then we can reopen the question.