# Different sorting schemes for different entry types?

Tags: biblatex

I'm writing my own style and for most entry types the `type` field must be printed *after* the title, but for some entries it must be printed *before*. So for some entry types I need the `type` field to be sorted before the `title` field, and for some I need it to be sorted after. Is there a way to do that?

---

MWE

```
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{abook,
    author = {Alfred A.},
    title = {A Book},
    type = {B Type}}
@book{anotherbook,
    author = {Alfred A.},
    title = {Another Book},
    type = {A Type}}
@article{anarticle,
    author = {Alfred A.},
    title = {An Article},
    type = {C Type}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[backend=biber, bibstyle=standard]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{
    \printnames{author}
    \newunit
    \printfield{title}
    \newunit
    \printfield{type}
}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{article}{
    \printnames{author}
    \newunit
    \printfield{type}
    \newunit
    \printfield{title}
}

\DeclareSortingScheme{nty}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
    \field{subtitle}
  }
  \sort{
    %\field{type}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
    \field{subtitle}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}

\begin{document}
  \nocite{*}
  \printbibliography
\end{document}
```

This is what I get:

[image]

Since it's sorted by `title` before `type`, "An Article" comes before "Another Book", when it should actually come last, since it's `type` starts with a "C".

Now if I uncomment that row that says `\field{type}` I get this:

[image]

Since it's sorted by `type` before `title`, "Another Book" comes before "A Book", when the opposite should be true.

---

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300010/how-to-adapt-the-sorting-of-a-custom-type-standard-in-using-biblatex-biber) suggests using the `sortkey` field, but in my case this won't work, since the author always comes first.

Comment: So we know none of the unspecified answers work, but you don't think we might need to see your code in order to come up with an alternative that does? Or that links to the other questions, together with an explanation of the problem with their workarounds, might not make it a bit easier for people to approach the problem, perhaps building on an existing answer?

Comment: @cfr Well, I honestly didn't think that was necessary, I was just hoping someone would point me in the right direction, but ok, I'll update my question, sorry.

Comment: You can't do type-specific sorting schemes as this doesn't make much sense, you'd be comparing different fields in the same steps in the sorting algorithm.

Comment: @PLK Ah, so there's no way to do what I need? It doesn't seem like such a crazy requirement. :(

Comment: I know it's annoying to be asked but why do you want to do this? It looks like you want it to look neater but that's not something to be addressed by sorting. You could have reference lists split by type and sorted differently instead?

Comment: @PLK well, I'm trying to follow Brazil's ABNT norms and sometimes they ask that the `type` be printed before and sometimes after the `title`, and the whole bibliography should should be sorted alphabetically letter by letter, so if the `type` is first it should be sorted first. If there's really no way to do that I might have to declare a new data model field to be used just for that so it doesn't get mixed up with the regular `type` field, but I'm trying to replace an existing `bibtex` style and people are already using `type`, so I'd rather not.

Comment: That is a really strange requirement - it's asking to sort the bibliography by the formatted strings which isn't really possible as the printing of the bibliography entries and their formatting/field ordering happens after sorting is already done. You can't even easily concat all fields together into a custom field and sort on that since the concat order isn't static. You could, I suppose, write a complex `\DeclareSourcemap` macro to describe the concat rules and concat into a new field and then sort on that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's an odd requirement since you will have to mirror the formatting somehow before the sorting happens. You could do it with sourcemaps by appending things to a custom field in the right order. Here is something to get you going which makes your MWE work:

```
\DeclareSourcemap{
  \maps[datatype=bibtex]{
    \map{
      \pertype{book}
      \step[fieldsource=title]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=type]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval, append]
    }
    \map{
      \pertype{article}
      \step[fieldsource=type]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval]
      \step[fieldsource=title]
      \step[fieldset=usera, origfieldval, append]
    }
  }
}
```

Then your sorting would be:

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{nty}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
    \field{subtitle}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{usera}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}
```

Although it's not really `nty` sorting any more and you should probably name it something else.