# Biblatex + biber - Sort citations by report issue

Tags: biblatex, sorting, report

I'm trying to sort some tech report citations from the same year in the bibliography by report issue number, but have got no chance so far, i've even tried adding the month in order to make them sort chronologically but it does not have any effect.

myreferences.bib

```
@techreport{VanBuskirk2014a,
address = {Sydney},
author = {{Van Buskirk}, Joe and Roxburgh, Amanda and Bruno, Raimondo and Burns, Lucinda},
institution = {National Drug and Alcohol Research Centre},
month = {mar},
number = {2},
pages = {1--14},
title = {{Drugs and The Internet}},
year = {2014}
}

@techreport{VanBuskirk2014b,
address = {Sydney},
author = {{Van Buskirk}, Joe and Roxburgh, Amanda and Bruno, Raimondo and Burns, Lucinda},
institution = {National Drug and Alcohol Research Centre},
month = {sep},
number = {3},
pages = {1--5},
title = {{Drugs and The Internet}},
year = {2014}
}
```

As i cite the VanBuskirk2014b before the VanBuskirk2014a it's ordered and numbered the wrong way, the september report gets the "a" key and is before in the bibliography whereas the march report gets the "b" key and goes after in the bibliography.

Here a reduced version to illustrate the problem:

test.tex

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}
\usepackage[bindingoffset=0.5cm, left=3cm, right=3cm, top=2.5cm, bottom=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[french]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=apa, sortcites=true]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{french}{french-apa}
\setlength\bibitemsep{1.5\itemsep}

\addbibresource{myreferences.bib}

\begin{document}

    \autocite{VanBuskirk2014b}\\

    \autocite{VanBuskirk2014a}

    \printbibliography

\end{document}
```

Comment: Adding the month doesn't help as all the standard sort schemes only consider the year when sorting, see [biblatex sorting by date](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/46868/35864) for sorting by the entire date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `sortyear` field to control the sorting manually, use it as `sortyear = {<year>-<number>}`

```
@techreport{VanBuskirk2014a,
  address = {Sydney},
  author = {{Van Buskirk}, Joe and Roxburgh, Amanda and Bruno, Raimondo and Burns, Lucinda},
  institution = {National Drug and Alcohol Research Centre},
  month = {mar},
  number = {2},
  pages = {1--14},
  title = {{Drugs and The Internet}},
  year = {2014},
  sortyear = {2014-2},
}

@techreport{VanBuskirk2014b,
  address = {Sydney},
  author = {{Van Buskirk}, Joe and Roxburgh, Amanda and Bruno, Raimondo and Burns, Lucinda},
  institution = {National Drug and Alcohol Research Centre},
  month = {sep},
  number = {3},
  pages = {1--5},
  title = {{Drugs and The Internet}},
  year = {2014},
  sortyear = {2014-3},
}
```

---

Technically, we could really sort by `number` as well, but since there is no way to restrict sorting to one type (see the recent [Different sorting schemes for different entry types?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307735/35864) and [how to adapt the sorting of a custom type `@standard` in using biblatex/biber](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/300010/35864)) that could mess up the sorting for other types that use `number`.

This is a version of the standard `nyvt` sorting, where the `volume` is also considered.

```
\DeclareSortingScheme{nynot}{
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{editor}
    \field{translator}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{number}
    \literal{0000}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, would you mind taking a look at [this](https://github.com/posquit0/Awesome-CV/pull/23/files)? You have far more experience with `biblatex` than me, and even i can see, that this is Bäh. I would hate if that gets distributed even further. Thanks.

Comment: @Johannes_B First off, the call to `biblatex` contains quite a few options, seeing that the drivers are rewritten from scratch et least the `doi`, `isbn`, `url` and `eprint` options are practically useless. The comment for the `backref` option is wrong (of course `backref=false` turns backrefs off). The `\AtBeginEnvironment{thebibliography}` block looks a bit fishy to me, but I don't know about that (I wouldn't change penalties unless I have to). The `\DeclareFieldFormat`s could be combined into one `\DeclareFieldFormat*{title}{#1\par}` and I'm not too fond of the `\par` in there.

Comment: ... (cont'd) The newly rewritten drivers are of course much simpler than the standard drivers. I don't like the `\par`s and the font commands, but OK. The `\par\vspace{0.3\baselineskip}` at the end looks fishy, one could better use `\bibitemsep` or similar for that. The `\DeclareNameFormat{author}` will of course explode with `biblatex` >= 3.3. The use of refsections for type filtering is also a bit naff, one could just use the same refsection everywhere and `type=...` in the option to `\printbibliography`.

Comment: It all started with a *I want to have the bibliography match the CV* issue. Can you leave a comment on github directly?

Comment: The original `friggery-cv` template already went havoc :-) I said i'll fix when 3.4 is around.