# Which bibliography entry type should I use for a document defining a European norm?

Tags: biblatex, bibliographies

I'm currently doing a research internship in the Photovoltaics laboratory of a university. I am writing my report, and in my bibliography, I would like to cite a document that is an International Standard for defining how to make measurements on photovoltaic systems.

More specifically, it's the international standard IEC 61724:1998 : *Photovoltaic system performance monitoring - Guidelines for measurement, data exchange and analysis*. [Here is an excerpt of the document](https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_iec61724%7Bed1.0%7Den.pdf). (unfortunately the full-text document is not available without paying)

Now, my question is: **Which BiblateX bibliography entry type should I use to cite this document? Article, Technical Report, Reference, Patent, ... ?**

Is there a bibliography entry type that is dedicated to this kind of documents (international standards)?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Maybe [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/300010/how-to-adapt-the-sorting-of-a-custom-type-standard-in-using-biblatex-biber) helps which also links to [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/65637/how-to-cite-a-standard-iso-etc-in-biblatex).

Comment: Are you OK with the answer in the linked question? (If so, can we close your question as duplicate?) If not, what do you need changed?

Comment: @moewe Yes, it's okay.